# Good combination of sans serif font text and math mode using beamer class

Tags: beamer, fonts, packages, sans-serif, computer-modern

Starting from this MWE,

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme[RGB={063,098,031}]{structure}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cmbright,sansmathaccent}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{L'operatore derivata: una curiosità}
Riassumendo un operatore $\hat{A}$ è un'istruzione matematica che applicata ad un oggetto matematico, diciamolo $\psi$, fornisce un altro oggetto matematico $\phi$ della stessa natura. Esso è scritto simbolicamente come, 
\[\hat{A}\psi=\phi\]
Un operatore semplice, per esempio, può contenere l'istruzione di costruire la derivata di una funzione. Allora, per una data funzione $\psi$ dipendente dalla variabile $x$ avremo:
\[\boxed{\hat{D}\psi=\frac{d\psi}{dx}=\phi}\]  
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I didn't want to use the classic CM fonts because with the default `beamer` fonts I don't like. Hence I have used `cmbright`, and I wanted fixed the accents using `sansmathaccent` package. But it is visible that the  ‘cmbright’ are too thin.

> Definitively why the use of `sansmathaccent` package doesn't place the accents correctly? Is there a closest possible font to have a good combination of sans serif font text and math mode in pdfLaTeX?

Comment: @downvoter: What is the reason of the downvote? Why am I using beamer?

Comment: +1: I had a similar problem. Your question and the nice answers are very helpful.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner You are very nice. From reading your comment I liked your style in play down ("sdrammatizzare" in Italian language it is better). :-)))))))..You're great.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some suggestions, in no particular order:

- I've had very good experiences with the `arev` sans-serif text and math font package in my `beamer` documents. It has thick strokes, which is extremely helpful if you're giving a presentation someplace where the projector or screen (or both...) generate low-contrast output. To use this font package, one also needs to run `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}`.
- The `10pt` document class option makes for small glyphs that are hard to read for people in the back row.
- Loading the `ragged2e` package with the `document` option enables hyphenation, making for altogether much less ragged-looking slides.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer} %  '10pt' makes for hard-to-follow presentations
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme[RGB={063,098,031}]{structure}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage{mathtools}

%\usepackage{cmbright,sansmathaccent}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{arev}

\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e} % <-- allow hyphenation

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\frametitle{L'operatore derivata: una curiosità}

Riassumendo un operatore $\hat{A}$ è un'istruzione matematica 
che applicata ad un oggetto matematico, diciamolo $\psi$, 
fornisce un altro oggetto matematico $\phi$ della stessa natura. 
Esso è scritto simbolicamente come, 
\[
\hat{A}\psi=\phi
\]

Un operatore semplice, per esempio, può contenere l'istruzione 
di costruire la derivata di una funzione. Allora, per una data 
funzione $\psi$ dipendente dalla variabile $x$ avremo:
\[
\boxed{\hat{D}\psi=\frac{d\psi}{dx}=\phi}
\]  

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi very kind...Mico. I'm making a document for a civics module for my students: inflation and the derivative that I'll have to explain :-). Thank youuuuuuuuuu.

Comment: @Sebastiano - Just out of curiosity: What kind of "inflation" are you talking about? Cosmic inflation, in a tiny tiny fraction of the first second after the Big Bang, or price inflation, i.e., when prices of goods and services change (often: increase) over time?

Comment: Yeah: the prices of goods and services change (often: increase) over time!!!

Comment: Wow, you're venturing from your professional territory (physics) into mine (economics). That's exciting! :-)

Comment: Surely there is a field invasion from me like in soccer stadiums ahahahah.

Answer (score 11):

For a Beamer presentation, you can always use modern fonts in LuaLaTeX or XeTeX.  You aren’t submitting it to one of the publishers who still forces you to use 8-bit fonts in 2021!

This actually lets you use any OpenType math font you want, including the serif ones.  But one attractive sans-serif math family is Kp Sans:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usecolortheme[RGB={063,098,031}]{structure}

\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{KpSans}
\setsansfont{KpSans}
\setmonofont{KpMono}
\setmathfont{KpMath-Sans}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{L'operatore derivata: una curiosità}
Riassumendo un operatore $\hat{A}$ è un'istruzione matematica che applicata ad un oggetto matematico, diciamolo $\psi$, fornisce un altro oggetto matematico $\phi$ della stessa natura. Esso è scritto simbolicamente come, 
\[\hat{A}\psi=\phi\]
Un operatore semplice, per esempio, può contenere l'istruzione di costruire la derivata di una funzione. Allora, per una data funzione $\psi$ dipendente dalla variabile $x$ avremo:
\[\boxed{\hat{D}\psi=\frac{d\psi}{dx}=\phi}\]  
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Kp Sans sample]

A close-up:

[image: Kp Math Sans sample]

A heavier sans-serif math font is Fira Math.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usecolortheme[RGB={063,098,031}]{structure}

\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[fira]{fontsetup}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{L'operatore derivata: una curiosità}
Riassumendo un operatore $\hat{A}$ è un'istruzione matematica che applicata ad un oggetto matematico, diciamolo $\psi$, fornisce un altro oggetto matematico $\phi$ della stessa natura. Esso è scritto simbolicamente come, 
\[\hat{A}\psi=\phi\]
Un operatore semplice, per esempio, può contenere l'istruzione di costruire la derivata di una funzione. Allora, per una data funzione $\psi$ dipendente dalla variabile $x$ avremo:
\[\boxed{\hat{D}\psi=\frac{d\psi}{dx}=\phi}\]  
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Fira Math sample]

Another font you might take a look at for presentations is the slab serif, GFS Neohellenic.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usecolortheme[RGB={063,098,031}]{structure}

\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures[GFSNeohellenic]{
  Ligatures={Common,TeX},
  UprightFont=*,
  BoldFont=*Bold,
  ItalicFont=*It,
  BoldItalicFont=*BoldIt,
  Extension=.otf}

\setmainfont{GFSNeohellenic}
\setsansfont{GFSNeohellenic}
\setmonofont{TeX Gyre Cursor}[Scale=MatchUppercase]
\setmathfont{GFSNeohellenicMath}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{L'operatore derivata: una curiosità}
Riassumendo un operatore $\hat{A}$ è un'istruzione matematica che applicata ad un oggetto matematico, diciamolo $\psi$, fornisce un altro oggetto matematico $\phi$ della stessa natura. Esso è scritto simbolicamente come, 
\[\hat{A}\psi=\phi\]
Un operatore semplice, per esempio, può contenere l'istruzione di costruire la derivata di una funzione. Allora, per una data funzione $\psi$ dipendente dalla variabile $x$ avremo:
\[\boxed{\hat{D}\psi=\frac{d\psi}{dx}=\phi}\]  
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: GFS Neohellenic sample]

[image: GFS Neohellenic Math sample]

Although you can use all the `fontspec` font options here, including `FakeBold=1.05`, a quick hack to slightly thicken an arbitrary font.

You can also kitbash an arbitrary OpenType font over a math font with, e.g.

```
\documentclass[10pt, professionalfonts]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme[RGB={063,098,031}]{structure}

\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}
\setsansfont{DejaVu Sans}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}
\setmathfont{Tex Gyre DejaVu Math}
\setmathfont{DejaVu Sans}[range=up]
\setmathfont{DejaVu Sans Oblique}[range=it]
\setmathfont{DejaVu Sans Bold}[range=bfup]
\setmathfont{DejaVu Sans Bold Oblique}[range=bfit]

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{L'operatore derivata: una curiosità}
Riassumendo un operatore $\hat{A}$ è un'istruzione matematica che applicata ad un oggetto matematico, diciamolo $\psi$, fornisce un altro oggetto matematico $\phi$ della stessa natura. Esso è scritto simbolicamente come, 
\[\hat{A}\psi=\phi\]
Un operatore semplice, per esempio, può contenere l'istruzione di costruire la derivata di una funzione. Allora, per una data funzione $\psi$ dipendente dalla variabile $x$ avremo:
\[\boxed{\hat{D}\psi=\frac{d\psi}{dx}=\phi}\]  
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: DejaVu Sans Sample]

Since these fonts won’t have math tables or superscripts/subscripts, your results may vary.  But here, since DejaVu, Arev and Bera all derive from Bitstream Vera, the appearance is very similar.

Comment: Kindest I thank you with all my heart always of your kindness that I reciprocate.