# Can I use parenthesis enumerate item style in beamer

Tags: beamer, enumerate

I want to use parenthesis style in enumerate environment in beamer class. Like

```
(1) text
(2) text
```

I could do this in article class by using

```
\begin{enumerate}[label = (\arabic*)]
\item blah
\item blah
\end{enumerate}
```

But this does not work in beamer class.

What should I do?

Comment: Actually I solved it by put
 \setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[default]
to preamble and in document using
 \begin{enuerate}[(1)] ... \end{enumerate}

Comment: If your comment solve your problem, please consider to rewrite it as answer in which you provide MWE, which show how your solution works :-). BTW, you not need to add `\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[default]` in document preamble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to use parenthesis style in `enumerate` environment in `beamer` class. .. But this does not work in `beamer` class.

Actually, it works just fine if the `enumitem` package is loaded.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{enumitem} % <-- essential
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{enumerate}[label = (\arabic*)]
  \item blah
  \item blah
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh... I forgot to include that package.. Thanks for reminding me!

Comment: @downvoter: Strangely enough, the user Mico has received a negative vote. I'm curious to understand the motivation. Maybe because he was using the beamer class and had answered to my question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/621378/good-combination-of-sans-serif-font-text-and-math-mode-using-beamer-class?